# Multiple registered events in JQuery

Tags: jquery, drupal

Posted this over at the Drupal forums but haven't received a response. Basically, I have a simple JavaScript item I developed for another website that I'm trying to port over into Drupal. It's basically a div with three tabs stacked on top of each other and an image. When the user scrolls over a tab, the image changes (depending on the tab scrolled over).

The progress I've made is as follows.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var imageOne = new Image(); imageOne.src = "images/slideshow/slideshow-image1.png";
var imageTwo = new Image(); imageTwo.src = "images/slideshow/slideshow-image2.png";
var imageThree = new Image(); imageThree.src = "images/slideshow/slideshow-image3.png";
var currentSlideshowImage = new Image();

$("#slideshow1").hover(
    function () {
        alert(imageOne.src);

        currentSlideshowImage = imageOne;
        document.getElementById("slideshow-image-object").src = currentSlideshowImage.src;
        document.getElementById('slideshow1').className = "active";
        document.getElementById('slideshow2').className = "";
        document.getElementById('slideshow3').className = "";
    }
);

$("#slideshow2").hover(
    function () {
        alert(imageTwo.src);

        currentSlideshowImage = imageTwo;

        document.getElementById("slideshow-image-object").src = currentSlideshowImage.src;

        document.getElementById('slideshow2').className = "active";
        document.getElementById('slideshow1').className = "";
        document.getElementById('slideshow3').className = "";
    }
);
```

});

Looking at the above code, there is a function attached to the hover event of two elements. For some reason, only the first event added will work. If I hover over slideshow1, the function calls as expected however slideshow2 does nothing. If I was to modify the code and move slideshow2 before slideshow1, the hover event on slideshow2 will run as expected however slideshow1 will do nothing.

Am I missing something simple here? Is this how I'd go about adding events to elements in my theme (this code is stored in an external file referenced in the .info theme file)? Any help at this point will be greatly appreciated.

Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: why are you repeating code? also, what does the html structure look like?

Comment: The code isn't repeated. It's operating on three different divs (although I only have two handlers set up). The HTML structure doesn't seem to matter. I've tried adding it to different elements of the page and consistently, it appears that only the first element works. If I moved the #slideshow2 handler above #slideshow1, it's hover event works but the #slideshow1 event stops working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery.hover() requires two arguments: a function to call on 'enter' and another on 'leave'.  The problem arrives when you leave the element, JQuery tries to call on null and throw an error. Try this instead (I've also taken the liberty of cleaning up your code to avoid repeating... yes, your code has useless repetitions) :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

// { elementId: url, ... }
var imgs = {
   'slideshow1': 'images/slideshow/slideshow-image1.png',
   'slideshow2': 'images/slideshow/slideshow-image3.png',
   'slideshow3': 'images/slideshow/slideshow-image3.png'
};
var currentSlideshowImage;  // no need to initialize now

$.each(imgs, function(id,url) {
   var img = new Image(); img.src = url;
   $('#' + id).hover(
      function() {
         currentSlideshowImage = img;
         $('#lideshow-image-object').attr('src', img.src);
         $(this).addClass('active');
      },
      function() {
         currentSlideshowImage = null;  // no image selected ?
         $(this).removeClass('active');
      }
   );
});

});  // JQuery.ready
```

You can add images to your slideshow using the convenient `imgs` object.

Comment: That is not true, if you pass only one function to `hover()` it will be called when you enter **and** leave the element. But nice cleanup of the code!

Comment: Thanks for that. Adding the 'leave' function works like a charm. Also thanks for the code clean-up. I made a few changes and it's working great.Just to make sure, I take it that the 'foreach' functions run at start-up, causing the images to be preloaded (which is why I had initially declared the variables at the top of my initial code)?On that point, should images be preloaded in the $.ready() function? Or is there a function that gets called earlier (iirc, $.ready() is called when everything is loaded or something along that line) where preloading might be more suitable?

Comment: it won't make much difference in the end, but I have put the imgs variable inside the $.ready function to avoid polluting the global namespace, which is a good habit by the way. You should use an element to store shared data instead of declaring "var foo;" etc. outside the $.ready function. But yes, images are preloaded when the DOM is ready.

Answer (score 1):

bits of advice

wrap your code up neatly.

and read this for info if you havent already

http://api.jquery.com/category/events/

events in jquery are a little tricky.

good luck.

Answer (score -1):

try declaring your variables outside of the $.ready() function.

Also I suggest you more fully embrace jQuery than you have so far. much of your code could be done much more succinctly

Comment: Yup, I suppose it's about time I got more acquainted with jQuery (and JS as a whole for that matter).

I don't see how declaring the variables outside the .ready() function would help in this case. Even the alert boxes I put in there to debug the code aren't being called.

Comment: that's because this has nothing to do with 'where the variables are declared' at all ...but definitely, you need to brush up on Javascript AND JQuery ;)